# C pointers malloc inside function call

Tags: c, function, pointers

I have such hierarchy:

```
main()
{
    int i;
    myStruct *devices = NULL;
    myFunc1(&devices);

    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        printf("MAC: %s, Name: %s, COD: %s\n\r", devices[i].field1, devices[i].field2, devices[i].field3);
    }
}

void myFunc1(myStruct **devices)
{
    myFunc2(devices);
}

void myFunc2(myStruct **devices)
{
    int i;
    *devices = malloc(sizeof(myStruct) * 5);

    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        (*devices[i]).field1 = "test1";
        (*devices[i]).field2 = "test2";
        (*devices[i]).field3 = "test3";
    }
}
```

At main when I access devices[i] with i = 0, it is ok, but when i > 0 SegFault happens, and I can not understand how to access it correctly.

Comment: Compile with all warnings and debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`). **Use the debugger** (`gdb`) and [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) if available.

Comment: @Dabo: no, that's a compilation error. clearly the code is not complete.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because of the [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) the expression `*devices[i]` is parsed as `*(devices[i])` which is not quite what you want. You want to use `(*devices)[i]` instead.

Comment: Thanks. Been struggling with this for some time now, never thought that problem is in assigning. :)

Answer (score 3):

I'm fairly sure

```
(*devices[i])
```

Should be

```
((*devices)[i])
```

Since [] operator takes precedence over the * operator. You want to dereference the pointer, and then access the array.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is that you are calling the wrong structure. First of all try to substitute

```
*devices[i]).field1
```

To

```
*devices[i])->field1
```